# ¿Como mostrar la imagen de la base de datos y la de default en PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, imagen

necesito de su ayuda, tengo una tabla de directivo, el cual necesito mostrar la foto de default cuando sea un usuario nuevo, en mi caso tengo un directivo con foto y otro que directivo nuevo, en el nuevo debe de verse la foto por default[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi código estoy metiendo un if para que valide la foto que agregue en la base de datos, la muestre en caso de que haya, en caso de que no, muestre la de default.

```
var mostrarDirectivos = function() {
    var tableDirectivo = $('#dataTableDirectivo').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": false,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo constant('URL'); ?>directivo/readtable"
        },
        "columns": [{
                defaultContent: "",
                'render': function(data, type, JsonResultRow, meta) {
                    var fullnameImagen = JsonResultRow.appaterno_director + '_' + JsonResultRow.apmaterno_director + '_' + JsonResultRow.nombre_director + '/' + JsonResultRow.foto_director;
                    var img = '<?php echo constant('URL'); ?>public/director/';
                    
                    if(img == null){
                        var fullnameImagen = JsonResultRow.appaterno_director + '_' + JsonResultRow.apmaterno_director + '_' + JsonResultRow.nombre_director + '/' + JsonResultRow.foto_director;
                        if(!file_exists(img)){
                            var img = '<?php echo constant('URL'); ?>public/director/';
                        }else{
                            var img = JsonResultRow.appaterno_director + '_' + JsonResultRow.apmaterno_director + '_' + JsonResultRow.nombre_director + '/' + JsonResultRow.foto_director;
                     }
                    }else{
                        var img = '<?php echo constant('URL'); ?>public/img/default.jpg';
                        return '<center><img src="' + img + '" class="rounded-circle img-fluid " style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"/></center>';
                    }
                    
                }
            },
            {
                defaultContent: "",
                "render": function(data, type, full) {
                    return full['nombre_director'] + ' ' + full['appaterno_director'] + ' ' + full['apmaterno_director'];
                }
            },
            {
                "data": "telefono_director"
            },
            {
                "data": "cedulaprofesional_director"
            },
            {
                data: null,
                "defaultContent": `<button class='consulta btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalDetalleDirectivo' title="Ver Detalles"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
            <button class='editar btn btn-warning' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalActualizarDirectivo' title="Editar Datos"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
            <button class='eliminar btn btn-danger' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalEliminarDirectivo' title="Eliminar Registro"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>`
            }
        ],
        "fnFooterCallback": function(nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay) {
            if (aiDisplay.length > 0) {
                $('body').removeClass('no-record');
            } else {
                $('body').addClass('no-record');
            }
        },
        responsive: true,
        autoWidth: false,
        language: idiomaDataTable,
        lengthChange: true,
        buttons: ['copy', 'excel', 'csv', 'pdf', 'colvis'],
        dom: 'Bfltip'
    });
    obtenerdatosDT(tableDirectivo);
}
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema o error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba quitando todo esto:

```
"columns": [{
                defaultContent: "",
                'render': function(data, type, JsonResultRow, meta) {
                    var fullnameImagen = JsonResultRow.appaterno_director + '_' + JsonResultRow.apmaterno_director + '_' + JsonResultRow.nombre_director + '/' + JsonResultRow.foto_director;
                    var img = '<?php echo constant('URL'); ?>public/director/';
                    
                    if(img == null){
                        var fullnameImagen = JsonResultRow.appaterno_director + '_' + JsonResultRow.apmaterno_director + '_' + JsonResultRow.nombre_director + '/' + JsonResultRow.foto_director;
                        if(!file_exists(img)){
                            var img = '<?php echo constant('URL'); ?>public/director/';
                        }else{
                            var img = JsonResultRow.appaterno_director + '_' + JsonResultRow.apmaterno_director + '_' + JsonResultRow.nombre_director + '/' + JsonResultRow.foto_director;
                     }
                    }else{
                        var img = '<?php echo constant('URL'); ?>public/img/default.jpg';
                        return '<center><img src="' + img + '" class="rounded-circle img-fluid " style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"/></center>';
                    }
                    
                }
            },
```

y lo sustituyes por esto:

```
        "columns": [{
                defaultContent: "",
                'render': function(data, type, JsonResultRow, meta) {
                    var fullnameImagen = JsonResultRow.appaterno_director + '_' + JsonResultRow.apmaterno_director + '_' + JsonResultRow.nombre_director + '/' + JsonResultRow.foto_director;
                    var urlImg = '<?php echo constant('URL'); ?>public/director/' + fullnameImagen;
                    var img = new Image();
                    img.src = urlImg;
                    if (img.height == 0) {
                        urlImg = '<?php echo constant('URL'); ?>public/img/default.jpg';
                    }
                    return '<center><img src="' + urlImg + '" class="rounded-circle img-fluid " style="width: 50px; 
                }
            },
```

### Explicación del error

Tu código anterior funcionaba mal y siempre mostraba la imagen por defecto porque justo antes del condicional, donde comprobabas esto:

```
if(img == null){
```

definias lo que esta `img` así:

```
var img = '<?php echo constant('URL'); ?>public/director/';
```

por lo tanto nunca podía ser **null** y por lo tanto siempre ejecutaba la segunda parte del condicional poniendo la imagen por defecto así:

```
}else{
  var img = '<?php echo constant('URL'); ?>public/img/default.jpg';
  return '<center><img src="' + img + '" class="rounded-circle img-fluid " style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"/></center>';
}
```

### Explicación de la solución

Como lo que nos interesa es saber si existe la imagen, en mi solución creo una nueva instancia de objeto de imagen HTML de javascript con [new Image()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image):

```
var img = new Image();
```

el cual, de saque no contiene nada, y le asigno como **src=** la imagen que teóricamente queremos saber si existe mediante:

```
img.src = urlImg;
```

donde **urlImg** se corresponde con la supuesta ruta que deberia tener la imagen (si existiera) y que he definido una línea antes con:

```
var urlImg = '<?php echo constant('URL'); ?>public/director/' + fullnameImagen;
```

Una vez hecho esto, que no da ningún error exista o no exista, una de las formas de comprobar si existe es mirar su altura. Al ser una imagen su altura debe ser superior a 0, porque sino no se veria nada, así que uso esa hipótesis para realizar el condicional siguiente:

```
if (img.height == 0) {
```

Si el resultado de esa propiedad es 0 entonces es que la imagen no existe, y por lo tanto se le debe poner la imagen por defecto:

```
urlImg = '<?php echo constant('URL'); ?>public/img/default.jpg';
```

y no hace falta un **else** porque en caso de que exista entonces urlImg ya está bien puesto de antes.  Y finalmente retorno toda la estructura de la imagen tal como ya hacias en tu código:

```
return '<center><img src="' + urlImg + '" class="rounded-circle img-fluid " style="width: 50px;
```

Espero te haya servido la explicación y hayas comprendido tanto el error como la solución.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda amigo, ejecutando el código, me manda solo la imagen de default, pero no me muestra en la tabla la imagen personal, me ejecuta, así como está en la primera imagen que subí en el post.

Comment: Quizás lo que está mal entonces es lo que resuelve `fullnameImagen`, lo cual ha sido copiado de tu código, pues no has indicado la ruta ni el nombre real donde tienes las imágenes subidas por los perfiles de los usuarios y me he creido lo que ponias. Revisa esa ruta a ver si está bien formada y modifica `fullnameImagen` para que apunte bien alli y deberia funcionarte bien

Comment: Si ejecuto el código que he puesto de forma independiente a lo que resuelve tu `fullnameImagen`, es decir, forzando que urlImg realmente exista, me funciona bien.  En [este enlace](https://jsfiddle.net/mwv02hq7/) lo verás, donde apunto a una imagen que carga bien. Por lo tanto, debes revisar como montas el `fullnameImagen` y sobretodo `urlImg` para apuntar correctamente a las imágenes del perfil de cada usuario, pues seguramente ahora devuelve una ruta incorrecta.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta amigo, ya estuve probando el código que me pusiste en el post, pero ya me muestra la de default con los usuarios nuevos, solo que cuando cambio la foto de perfil no me la toma en cuenta y no cambia de foto.

Comment: Y ese cambio que haces de la foto del perfil, cuando actualizas la página donde tienes el código de la pregunta, ¿no aparece bien?  Quizás es que no la estas guardando con el nombre correcto (lo que se corresponderia con `fullnameImangen`) y por eso no aparece.  O bien, quizás esperas que una vez actualizada la foto del perfil, quizás desde un modal, al cerrar el modal no estás actualizando la tabla de nuevo y hasta que no la recarges no saldrá el cambio. (no lo se porque no has indicado como se actualiza la foto ni que ocurre entonces)

Comment: Buenas colegas de nuevo, me puedes explicar el código, al parecer ya funciono. Gracias por su aporte!

Comment: @DanielHorta Acabo de poner una explicación detallada. Recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta si crees que cumple con tu pregunta para que la comunidad lo sepa y no quede pendiente eternamente, gracias. Saludos